# JSTL Error when iterating through response object

Tags: jsp, jstl

I get the following error in my jstl code.

> Illegal use of <when>-style tag without <choose> as its direct parent

```
<c:forEach var="hl" items="${hotelList}" varStatus="status">
  <c:when test="${status.index == 0}">                                                
    <option selected="selected" value="${hl.hotelId}">${hl.hotelName}</option>                                            
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <option value="${hl.hotelId}">${hl.hotelName}</option>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:forEach>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<c:when>` works inside `<c:choose>` tag

try this

```
<c:forEach var="hl" items="${hotelList}" varStatus="status">
    <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${status.index == 0}">
            <option selected="selected" value="${hl.hotelId}">${hl.hotelName}</option>
      </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
           <option value="${hl.hotelId}">${hl.hotelName}</option>
     <c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```